# Properly using the Count Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In the Enrollment_Changes table, the phone model listed is the phone the subscriber changed FROM on that date.

If there is no subsequent change on Enrollment_Changes, the phone the subscriber changed TO is listed on the P_Enrollment table

For example, subscriber 12345678 enrolled on 1/5/2011 with a RAZR.  On 11/1/2011 he changed FROM the RAZR.  You can see what he changed TO with the next transaction on Enrollment_Changes on 05/19/2012.

How would you find the Count of subs that first enrolled with the iPhone 3?

Here is the code I have for creating the tables

Create Tables: TBL 1

```
USE [Test2]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[P_ENROLLMENT]    ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[P_ENROLLMENT](
    [Subid ] [float] NULL,
    [Enrollment_Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Channel] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Region] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Active_Status] [float] NULL,
    [Drop_Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Phone_Model] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

TBL 2

```
USE [Test2]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ENROLLMENT_CHANGES]     ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ENROLLMENT_CHANGES](
    [Subid] [float] NULL,
    [Cdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Phone_Model] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Insert TBL1

```
INSERT INTO [P_ENROLLMENT]([Subid ], [Enrollment_Date], [Channel], [Region], [Active_Status], [Drop_Date], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12345678, '2011-01-05 00:00:00', 'Retail', 'Southeast', 1, NULL, 'iPhone 4');

INSERT INTO [P_ENROLLMENT]([Subid ], [Enrollment_Date], [Channel], [Region], [Active_Status], [Drop_Date], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12346178, '2011-03-13 00:00:00', 'Indirect Dealers', 'West', 1, NULL, 'HTC Hero');

INSERT INTO [P_ENROLLMENT]([Subid ], [Enrollment_Date], [Channel], [Region], [Active_Status], [Drop_Date], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12346679, '2011-05-19 00:00:00', 'Indirect Dealers', 'Southeast', 0, '2012-03-15 00:00:00', 'Droid 2');

INSERT INTO [P_ENROLLMENT]([Subid ], [Enrollment_Date], [Channel], [Region], [Active_Status], [Drop_Date], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12347190, '2011-07-25 00:00:00', 'Retail', 'Northeast', 0, '2012-05-21 00:00:00', 'iPhone 4');

INSERT INTO [P_ENROLLMENT]([Subid ], [Enrollment_Date], [Channel], [Region], [Active_Status], [Drop_Date], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12347701, '2011-08-14 00:00:00', 'Indirect Dealers', 'West', 1, NULL, 'HTC Hero');

INSERT INTO [P_ENROLLMENT]([Subid ], [Enrollment_Date], [Channel], [Region], [Active_Status], [Drop_Date], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12348212, '2011-09-30 00:00:00', 'Retail', 'West', 1, NULL, 'Droid 2');

INSERT INTO [P_ENROLLMENT]([Subid ], [Enrollment_Date], [Channel], [Region], [Active_Status], [Drop_Date], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12348723, '2011-10-20 00:00:00', 'Retail', 'Southeast', 1, NULL, 'Southeast');

INSERT INTO [P_ENROLLMENT]([Subid ], [Enrollment_Date], [Channel], [Region], [Active_Status], [Drop_Date], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12349234, '2012-01-06 00:00:00', 'Indirect Dealers', 'West', 0, '2012-02-14 00:00:00', 'West');

INSERT INTO [P_ENROLLMENT]([Subid ], [Enrollment_Date], [Channel], [Region], [Active_Status], [Drop_Date], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12349745, '2012-01-26 00:00:00', 'Retail', 'Northeast', 0, '2012-04-15 00:00:00', 'HTC Hero');

INSERT INTO [P_ENROLLMENT]([Subid ], [Enrollment_Date], [Channel], [Region], [Active_Status], [Drop_Date], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12350256, '2012-02-11 00:00:00', 'Retail', 'Southeast', 1, NULL, 'iPhone 4');

INSERT INTO [P_ENROLLMENT]([Subid ], [Enrollment_Date], [Channel], [Region], [Active_Status], [Drop_Date], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12350767, '2012-03-02 00:00:00', 'Indirect Dealers', 'West', 1, NULL, 'Sidekick');

INSERT INTO [P_ENROLLMENT]([Subid ], [Enrollment_Date], [Channel], [Region], [Active_Status], [Drop_Date], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12351278, '2012-04-18 00:00:00', 'Retail', 'Midwest', 1, NULL, 'iPhone 3');

INSERT INTO [P_ENROLLMENT]([Subid ], [Enrollment_Date], [Channel], [Region], [Active_Status], [Drop_Date], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12351789, '2012-05-08 00:00:00', 'Indirect Dealers', 'West', 0, '2012-07-04 00:00:00', 'iPhone 3');

INSERT INTO [P_ENROLLMENT]([Subid ], [Enrollment_Date], [Channel], [Region], [Active_Status], [Drop_Date], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12352300, '2012-06-24 00:00:00', 'Retail', 'Midwest', 1, NULL, 'Droid 2');

INSERT INTO [P_ENROLLMENT]([Subid ], [Enrollment_Date], [Channel], [Region], [Active_Status], [Drop_Date], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12352811, '2012-06-25 00:00:00', 'Retail', 'Southeast', 1, NULL, 'Sidekick');
```

Insert TBL2

```
INSERT INTO [ENROLLMENT_CHANGES]([Subid], [Cdate], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12345678, '2011-11-01 00:00:00', 'RAZR');

INSERT INTO [ENROLLMENT_CHANGES]([Subid], [Cdate], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12346178, '2012-01-07 00:00:00', 'HTC Hero');

INSERT INTO [ENROLLMENT_CHANGES]([Subid], [Cdate], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12348723, '2012-01-28 00:00:00', 'RAZR');

INSERT INTO [ENROLLMENT_CHANGES]([Subid], [Cdate], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12350256, '2012-02-21 00:00:00', 'Blackberry Bold');

INSERT INTO [ENROLLMENT_CHANGES]([Subid], [Cdate], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12349745, '2012-05-05 00:00:00', 'HTC Hero');

INSERT INTO [ENROLLMENT_CHANGES]([Subid], [Cdate], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12345678, '2012-05-19 00:00:00', 'Palm Pre');

INSERT INTO [ENROLLMENT_CHANGES]([Subid], [Cdate], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12347190, '2012-05-20 00:00:00', 'HTC Hero');

INSERT INTO [ENROLLMENT_CHANGES]([Subid], [Cdate], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12350256, '2012-05-21 00:00:00', 'Blackberry Bold');

INSERT INTO [ENROLLMENT_CHANGES]([Subid], [Cdate], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12349234, '2012-06-04 00:00:00', 'Palm Pre');

INSERT INTO [ENROLLMENT_CHANGES]([Subid], [Cdate], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12346178, '2012-06-05 00:00:00', 'iPhone 3');

INSERT INTO [ENROLLMENT_CHANGES]([Subid], [Cdate], [Phone_Model]) 
    VALUES(12350767, '2012-06-10 00:00:00', 'iPhone 3');
```

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, and I'm not sure I do, I think that the first model is in p_enrollment if there are no entries in enrollment_changes, otherwise it's in the first entry of enrollment_changes.  Is that right?

Comment: Great job on your first SO question, including ALL the DDL. I would give you 5 stars if I could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the count

```
select COUNT(*) Total
from
(
    select e.*,
        rn = row_number() over (partition by e.subid order by c.cdate desc),
        first_model = coalesce(c.phone_model, e.phone_model)
    from [P_ENROLLMENT] e
    left join [ENROLLMENT_CHANGES] c on c.subid = e.subid
) x
where rn=1 and first_model = 'iPhone 3'
```

---

For all the records

```
select *
from
(
    select e.*,
        rn = row_number() over (partition by e.subid order by c.cdate desc),
        first_model = coalesce(c.phone_model, e.phone_model)
    from [P_ENROLLMENT] e
    left join [ENROLLMENT_CHANGES] c on c.subid = e.subid
) x
where rn=1 and first_model = 'iPhone 3'
order by subid
```

Comment: I think this logic is right, but the request was for the COUNT.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know if the first record in the table is an iPhone 3.  Something like this:

```
select count(*)
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by subid order by enrollment_date) as seqnum
      from p_enrollment e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1 and phone_model = 'iPhone 3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm thinking too simply, but wouldn't either of the following do what you're looking for?:

```
SELECT      Phone_Model
            , COUNT(*) AS Initially_Enrolled
FROM        p_enrollment
GROUP BY    Phone_Model
```

(working SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68258/4)

or

```
SELECT      COUNT(*) AS Initially_Enrolled
FROM        p_enrollment
WHERE       Phone_Model = 'iPhone 3'
```

(working SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68258/3)

Since you only want initial enrollment, the ENROLLMENT_CHANGES table is irrelevant.

Comment: You *may* be thinking too simply. I believe the p_enrolment contains the CURRENT value and _changes contains the historical values.